# How should I make code over two digits by Psychopy

Tags: digits, psychopy

I'm using Psychopy to get two digits through keyboard and as a feedback to show a participant correctness or incorrectness on the window. Though I write in the code view as follows, it doesn't work. Actually, 'slash' is mistakenly contained in z variable due to using 'slash' as a routine end key. Also, I'm in trouble with int(z), where there is invalid literal for int() with base10.

```
theseKeys = event.getKeys(KeyList={'1','0'})
z = theseKeys[0]
z = int(z)
m = theseKeys[1]
m = int(m)
z = 10*z + m

if z == correct:
     Ans = 1
else
     Ans = 0
trial.addData('z',z)
```

I add more questions as follows:

Thank you for answering my question, but it didn't work either.
I did what you advised in builder as follows, but variable y didn't contain number, and the trial starts 2 seconds later.

```
z=0 
y = event.getKeys(keyList=['0','1'])
if len(y) > 0: 
   z = y.pop(0) 
   z = int(z) 
if len(y) > 0:
   m = y.pop(0) 
   m = int(m) 
   z = 10*z + m
if z == correct:
     Ans = 1
else
     Ans = 0
trial.addData('z',z)
```

Comment: Do you make the experiment in Builder or Coder? The syntax is `event.getKeys(keyList=['1', '0'])` with a small 'k' and a proper list.

Comment: This code can break in so many ways. You need to be coding more defensively, such as wrapping your variable assignments within a check that the list is not actually empty, or contains only one entry.